# Not Getting Updated using Cursor in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle11g

```
declare cursor C1 is select vc_emp_id ,vc_rep_to from hrpay.persdet where vc_emp_id in
(select vc_emp_id from hrpay.mst_timesheet 
 where vc_cur_mgr_id = '85' and vc_status = 'P'and vc_emp_id =1214);
 begin for emp_rec in C1 loop
 update 
 hrpay.mst_timesheet set vc_cur_mgr_id =emp_rec.vc_rep_to 
  where vc_cur_mgr_id = '85' and vc_status ='P'and vc_emp_id=emp_rec.vc_emp_id; 
 commit; 
 end loop; end;
```

Have declared  CURSOR BUT  its not updating the same.

Comment: You should not have COMMIT within loop. Should commit only when your all transaction done.

Comment: Why are you using a loop for this at all? A single correlated update would be simpler and more efficient. We can't see your table structures or the data before or after you execute this; you'll need to debug the cursor query (does that find anything on its own?), check the data is as you actually expect (and committed if you're inserting/running this/querying across multiple sessions), data type match, etc.

Comment: For testing purpose here i am doing single update but i have to do multiple updates and vc_cur_mgr_id has to be come dynamically according to current vc_emp_id .

Answer (score 2):

According to your predicat, where you have vc_emp_id =1214, you could try this:

```
update hrpay.mst_timesheet
set vc_cur_mgr_id = (select vc_emp_id
                    from hrpay.persdet
                    where vc_emp_id = 1214 
                      and rownum = 1)
where vc_cur_mgr_id = '85'
  and vc_status = 'P'
  and vc_emp_id = 1214;
```

Comment: thanks but i want to do multiple updates . For testing purpose here i have included vc_emp_id in where clause .